# How to make CSS Multi Column layout over html to move between the columns on user click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html file where I apply css3 multi layout over it.

```
#div1 {
     column-width: 640px;
     column-gap:1000px;
     column-rule: 1px solid red;
     height:620px;
     -ms-hyphens: auto;
     text-align:center;
     direction: rtl;
     padding-left:50px;
     padding-right:50px;
}
```

When Html tag style has `overflow-x: scroll` I can see all the columns by scrolling horizontally.
I need to show only 1 column at a time and move between them when user clicks on the division to the left or right. If I make `overflow-x: hidden` scroll wont appear and only 1 column appear. Now how can I move to next or previous column when clicking to left or right ? Is it possible by javascript ?

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/animate/. On button click use it to make scrolled column animated (for example by changing left offset ), and also hide other columns.

Comment: For this question demo would be useful. In general pretty simple to accomplish: you have `column-width` and `column-gap`, so just add a little javascript to show necessary column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[This](http://jsbin.com/torop/3/edit)** will give you an idea on how to start:

CSS

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div {  
  position: relative;
  width: 1400px;
  column-width: 640px;
 column-gap: 120px;
  column-rule: 1px solid red;
  height: 240px;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  text-align:center;
  direction: rtl;
  padding-left:50px;
  padding-right:50px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  var body = $('body');
  var div = $('div');
  body.click(function(e){    
    var half = body.width()/2;
    var width = 800;
    var direction = '+=';
    if(e.clientX > half) direction = '-=';
    div.animate({left: direction+width});
  });  
});
```

Notice you still need to limit the movement. I'm using CSS relative position to move the div, but you can use the scroll value but it's a little more tricky.
IMHO you should use [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) or [any other way](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/display) instead of columns for this purpose cuz they are kinda hard to control.

Comment: any idea how to limit the movement when beginning and end of file reached? I did try to check the window.pageXOffset value but it is always 0

Comment: you can use the [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) of the element or the [left css property](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to get the x value ..  and it must be between 0 and the body width.